# using $translate inside a controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to use `$translate` inside my controller and when I change the language all strings get translated, this works when I use : `{{'Menu.CANDIDATURES.VIEW' | translate}}` but I want to use it on my controller as well.

for this I used `$watch` as following :

```
.controller('CandidaturesDatatableCtrl', function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $filter) {

    $scope.view = '';
    $scope.update = '';
    $scope.delete = '';

    $scope.$watch(
      function() { return $filter('translate')('ACTIONS.VIEW'); },
      function(newval) { $scope.view = newval; console.log(newval); }
    );

    $scope.$watch(
      function() { return $filter('translate')('ACTIONS.UPDATE'); },
      function(newval) { $scope.update = newval }
    );

    $scope.$watch(
      function() { return $filter('translate')('ACTIONS.DELETE'); },
      function(newval) { $scope.delete = newval }
    );

   // deleted code
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
          if (true) {
            return '<button class="btn btn-blue btn-primary btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b mb-10"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>'+$scope.view+'</span></button>&nbsp;'
              + '<button class="btn btn-bl btn-success btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b mb-10"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>'+$scope.update+'</span></button>&nbsp;'
              + '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b mb-10"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>'+$scope.delete+'</span></button>';
          } else {
            return '';
          }

        })
    ];
  });
```

`$watch` is working fine as you can see on my code there is a `console.log(newval)` which logs the new translation, but $scope.view, $scope.update and $scopte.delete are not getting translated after I change the language, so I need to refresh my page to see the new translation.

How can I solve that ?

as you can see also the code I wrote is very ugly, if you know some other way I'll be grateful.

## Edit:

I tried to use the `$translateChangeSuccess` event instead of `$watch` as following :

```
 .controller('CandidaturesDatatableCtrl', function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $filter, $rootScope, $translate) {

    $scope.view = $filter('translate')('ACTIONS.VIEW');
    $scope.update = $filter('translate')('ACTIONS.UPDATE');
    $scope.delete = $filter('translate')('ACTIONS.DELETE');

    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function() {
      $translate(['ACTIONS.VIEW','ACTIONS.UPDATE','ACTIONS.DELETE']).then(function (newval) {
        console.log(newval);
        $scope.view = newval['ACTIONS.VIEW'];
        $scope.update = newval['ACTIONS.UPDATE'];
        $scope.delete = newval['ACTIONS.DELETE'];
      });
    });
//...
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
          if (true) {
            return '<button class="btn btn-blue btn-primary btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b mb-10"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>'+$scope.view+'</span></button>&nbsp;'
              + '<button class="btn btn-bl btn-success btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b mb-10"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>'+$scope.update+'</span></button>&nbsp;'
              + '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b mb-10"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>'+$scope.delete+'</span></button>';
          } else {
            return '';
          }

        })
    ];
  });
```

But it didn't work I got the same behavior as when I use `$watch`.

To see how my code works, this is the state of the page when I load it :

[image]

the previous page is in french, and then when I change it to English :

[image]

as you can see all the labels got translated to English except `Afficher`, `Modifier` and `Supprimer` which I translate in the controller, and you can notice a log in the console which means that `$translateChangeSuccess` has worked but it couldn't change the values in the view.

Comment: are you using angular-translate? if yes, have a look at the $translate service. https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service

Comment: @sdfacre yes I already read that article, my question wasn't about how to use $translate as I said it works but I have to refresh the webpage in my case to see the effects.

Answer (score 1):

don't really like to see those watchers.... You can actually listen to some events, i.e. $translateChangeSuccess

here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/njVZQ2plsXK95JvuxP1J?p=preview

```
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function(){
  $translate(['ACTIONS.VIEW', 'ACTIONS.UPDATE']).then(function (result) {
    $scope.view = result['ACTIONS.VIEW'];
    $scope.update= result['ACTIONS.UPDATE'];
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm afraid to say that it didn't work, please check my latest edit for more further informations.

Comment: sorry, just realized that the buttons were actually rendered using string. why did you do that? isn't there an Angular way of doing it? If you can't change the buttons, probably try to move the button configuration into the $translate resolver, so you re-render the buttons after the language changed.

Comment: I use angular-datatables which and the only way to add a column to it with html code is to render that html, sorry but I dont know how to move that html code into the $translate resolver

Comment: I think this example http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWayDataChange is like yours and it doesn't use html code in controller.